# how to print 111112223455566666 using for, while or repeat?

Tags: r, loops

I could print something like below by running

```
for(i in 1:5) print(i,i))
```

**I'm using R here :)**

```
[1] 1

[1] 2 2

[1] 3 3 3 

[1] 4 4 4 4 

[1] 5 5 5 5 5
```

but I couldn't really find a way to print something like below. 
Can anyone open my eyes please?

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

[1] 2 2 2

[1] 3

[1] 4

[1] 5 5 5

[1] 6 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking to `print` using `for` loop, create a sequence with `seq`

```
i1 <- seq(1, 5, 2)
i2 <- c(rev(i1), i1)
for(i in 1:6) print(rep(i, i2[i]))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
#[1] 2 2 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 5 5 5
#[1] 6 6 6 6 6
```

---

If we need as a `vector`, then use `rep`

```
rep(1:6,  i2)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach using  `mapply` . It doesn't use for or while clauses though.

```
a1<-1:6
a2<-c(5,3,1)

paste(mapply(rep,list(1:6),list(c(a2,rev(a2)))),collapse="", sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 6
for(i in 1:n) print(rep(i, max(1, 2*abs(i - (n+1)/2))))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1
#[1] 2 2 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 5 5 5
#[1] 6 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!